# How to reposition a relative DIV using left/top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a `div` with the attribute `position: relative;`. Now, there are three of these `div`s. They all get a unique ID etc.

Now if I click a `div`, I want it to animate to a certain position in the document. Although I cannot determine the left/top values since if I use "top" and "left", it will relatively set the left to its parents position.

Maybe a bit unclear, but here is what I got.

The CSS of the clickable `DIV` that will move.

```css
div#left_hldr .switch_project {
  z-index: 1001;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
// Open project.
$(".switch_project").live('click', function() {

  // Get the ID value.
  var More_Id = $(this).attr("id");

  // Explode the Id.
  var Id_Split = More_Id.split("_");

  // Get the project ID.
  var Project_Id = Id_Split[2];

  /*
      Replacement of the switch project div.
      1 ) Define the current position.
      2 ) Define the new position.
      3 ) Replace the DIV to the new position.
      4 ) Fade the new page in.
      5 ) Put the DIV back to its original position.
  */

  // Current Position.
  var Ori_Left = $(this).offset().left;
  var Ori_Top = $(this).offset().top;

  // New Position.  [ Based on the content_hldr container ]
  var New_Top = $("div#content_hldr").offset().top;
  var New_Left = $("div#content_hldr").offset().left;

  // Define the current div.
  var Div_Rep = $(this);

  // Hide the More Info tab.
  $(Div_Rep).children(".more_info").fadeOut("fast");

  // Fade content out.
  $("div#content_hldr").fadeOut("fast");

  // Replace the div.
  $(Div_Rep).animate({
    top: New_Top,
    left: New_Left
  }, "slow", function() {

    // Load Home page in.
    $("div#content_hldr").load("content/content.projects.php?id=" + Project_Id, function() {

      // Re-define Cufon.
      Cufon.replace('h2');
    });
    // Fade in the content.
    $("div#content_hldr").fadeIn("fast", function() {

      // Hide the replaced div.
      $(Div_Rep).hide();

      // Replace it back to its position.
      $(Div_Rep).css({
        top: Ori_Top,
        left: Ori_Left
      });

      // Show the More Info tab again.
      $(Div_Rep).children(".more_info").show();

      // Fade back in.
      $(Div_Rep).fadeIn("medium");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If I use "position: absolute", it first moves the div to the left upper corner.

Comment: try to add left and top values with it

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is: what does this code *not* do that you expect it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...it will relatively set the left to its parents position.

Actually, no. If you use `left` and `top` with a `position: relative` element, they'll offset it from where it otherwise would be if it weren't positioned (e.g., in the static flow), while continuing to reserve its space in the static flow. A subtle but important distinction (and hugely useful for drag-and-drop).

If you want to animate it to the top left of the document, you can figure out its offset (via [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)), and then provide those as negative numbers for `left` and `top`, since of course if it's at (say) [100,50], then positioning it at [-100,-50] compared to its default position will...put it at [0,0].

Like this:

```
$("selector_for_your_divs").click(function() {
    var pos, $this;
    $this = $(this);
    pos = $this.offset();
    $this.animate({
        left: "-" + pos.left + "px",
        top:  "-" + pos.top  + "px"
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arive5)

Similarly, if you want to move it to be where another element is, simply subtract its position from the other element's position — that gives you the delta to apply:

```
$("selector_for_your_divs").click(function() {
    var mypos, otherpos, $this;

    // Move to the target element
    $this = $(this);
    pos = $this.offset();
    otherpos = $('selector_for_other_element').offset();
    pos.left = otherpos.left - pos.left;
    pos.top  = otherpos.top  - pos.top;
    $this.animate({
        left: pos.left + "px",
        top:  pos.top  + "px"
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arive5/3)

Comment: @Roel: No worries. I may have just added the tweaking for you, I realized your target element wasn't precisely at 0,0 and did an update (apparently as you were accepting the answer). :-)